# DNN Error - Default.aspx?tabid=482&error=An unexpected error has occurred&content=0

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke-7

I have installed DNN 7 correctly without any error, also I have added a child page(testdemo) to the dnndev.me site. It worked perfectly, then i have added a module and added that module to the childpage(dnndev.me/testdemo). I have installed skins, it is also applied perfectly. **[Also it was found in portal/_default/skins folder]**

Next I have edited the module [Not a big one, just added a label box with text] and build the solution, then while giving refresh in the dnndev.me/testdemo page it shows DNN Error

In the address tab it shows -

> http://dnndev.me/Default.aspx?tabid=482&error=An%20unexpected%20error%20has%20occurred&content=0

Even the normal ddndev.me is also not running showing the same,

so i opened the Portal/_default/logs file, I found the following error,

```
2014-08-01 13:03:57,333 [USER6-PC][Thread:40][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase - An error has occurred while loading page.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.GetSkin(PageBase page)
   at DotNetNuke.Framework.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

2014-08-01 13:03:57,333 [USER6-PC][Thread:40][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - ~/Default.aspx?tabid=55&error=terminate
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.GetSkin(PageBase page)
   at DotNetNuke.Framework.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

2014-08-01 13:03:57,337 [USER6-PC][Thread:40][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.GetSkin(PageBase page)
   at DotNetNuke.Framework.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Still it shows more at the top, but space wont be sufficient to paste all..

Can anyone solve this issue??

Comment: I haven't used DNN before, but from the Stack Trace, it appears DNN is expecting `PageBase` to have a `Skin`.

Comment: i too taught the same and checked in the folders but i found all the skins. Will check on the web config and try to set the default skin

Comment: Nope!! I didn't find anything about that in config file :(

Comment: Can some one help me???

Comment: I cleared this by re-installing the whole dnn :(